# AWS CodeDeploy - appspec.yml not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy

I am attempting to deploy via AWS CodeDeploy. However it always fails at before-insatll with the following error.

> No such file or directory -
>   /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/xxxxx/xxxxxx/deployment-archive/appspec.yml

The ZIP files that I have loaded in S3 bucket is following the defined structure here.

```
  |--content (subfolder)
  |    |--myTextFile.txt
  |    |--mySourceFile.rb
  |    |--myExecutableFile.exe
  |    |--myInstallerFile.msi
  |    |--myPackage.rpm
  |    |--myImageFile.png
  |--scripts (subfolder)
  |    |--myShellScript.sh
  |    |--myBatchScript.bat 
  |    |--myPowerShellScript.ps1 
  |--appspec.yml
```

I really can't figure out what is going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For another possible solution, also see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740298/jenkins-triggered-code-deploy-is-failing-at-applicationstop-step-even-though-sam/38770917#38770917

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It seems CodeDeploy cannot find the component files, which results in a failed deployment. Could you make sure that when unzip the bundle, all the files are extracted to the current directory not a new folder?
- Not sure if you are bundling in mac os, but we do have a troubleshooting on this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-bundle-with-finder